# Is retired astronaut Scott Kelly now the same height as his brother?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, medical, long-duration

In WIRED's new video [Astrophysicist Explains One Concept in 5 Levels of Difficulty | WIRED](https://youtu.be/QcUey-DVYjk?t=160) "Astrophysicist Janna Levin, PhD, is asked to explain the concept of gravity to 5 different people; a child, a teen, a college student, a grad student, and an expert."

At about `02:40` retired astronaut Scott Kelly is said to have "elongated" during his year in space and was significantly but temporarily taller than his identical twin brother upon returning to Earth.

Are there any sources that mention if commander Kelly has returned to his pre-ISS height and/or that of his brother retired astronaut and shuttle commander, and US Senate candidate [Mark Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Kelly)?

[image]

Comment: And, have they reached mustache equivalence?

Comment: Everybody gains height during sleep in the night. We are a little taller in the morning than in the evening before going to bed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark Kelly, told CNN's "Erin Burnett OutFront" by email, [Scott Kelly's life, height return to normal after near year in space](https://www.cnn.com/2016/03/03/us/astronaut-scott-kelly-houston/index.html), that his brother is back to his normal height.

> Astronaut Scott Kelly, who grew about 2 inches during his nearly one year stay on the International Space Station, is back to his normal height, his identical twin brother, Mark, said Thursday.
>
> Scott Kelly, whose spine elongated while he spent 340 days in space, took less than two days to shrink.
>
> **Mark Kelly, a former astronaut, told CNN's "Erin Burnett OutFront" by email that the two went back-to-back an hour after his brother returned to the United States early Thursday.**
>
> Scott grew 1½ inches before returning to normal, he said.

Comment: It appears that the "official" measurement was initially about two inches difference. Then they stood back-to-back and measured 1.5 inches -- perhaps two days after landing? Two days later, no difference. I hope some details can be confirmed.

Comment: It would be interesting to compare two computer tomograms of the vertebral colum, one just before launch and one immediately after landing. The height difference should be caused only by the intervertebral discs.